# Programmatically installing the application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I like to install the .app programmatically from my application. I hope it can be done only through jailbrokken iPhones. Can anyone share some knowledge regarding this. I found a application called "CallMe" in cydia store. This application programmatically installs the other one. Or how to install the iPhone applications (.app) file in the iPhone from the terminal. If we programmatically execute those system commands, I hope it's possible to install the application programmatically in jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: @Sadiq : Got the ans for your questn? I have a similar issue. can u pls share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you only need to download (somehow) and put the unpacked application in /var/mobile/Applications on the phone. Look at the existing structure (with a terminal, on a jailbroken phone) and follow it.

Comment: Thanks a lot chalm, only this much is enough to accomplish the programmatic installation. we doesnt need to run any scripts or call system commands to install the new applications . Much breif answers will help to solve this issue.

Comment: I have checked this blog , http://chrisalvares.com/blog/?tag=iphone-daemon , which says that .app needs to be placed in /Applications. I need the app icon to be placed in the Springboard also. So any idea or suggestion on programmatic installation and uninstallation would be greatly appreciated.